# find data inside mysql table with 30,000 records

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am running Apache server with PHP and MySQL.

I want to make a simple search engine that finds articles which contain a certain string.

I have 30,000 documents with separated pages (I mean, total 30,000 files)

I think there are two ways to do the task.

1. Insert 30,000 records(rows) to the table. then `mysql_query` to find the records which have the query string.
2. Insert 30 records(rows) with 1000 articles per each. then `mysql_query` to find the records that have the query string, then PHP `explode` to separate articles..

which one is faster?

I will use `Select * from mytable where contenttext LIKE '%querystring%'`

The main concept is that

1. use `mysql_query` with % wildcard in 30,000 documents
2. use `mysql_query` with % wildcard in 30 documents followed by searching again with PHP `explode` and `strpos`.

Thanks!

---

more detail:

1. first concept -> insert whole records each

   row 1 : filename=aaaa1.doc, content=stack overflow is the site that...

   row 2 : filename=aaaa2.doc, content=stack exchange is the site that...

   row 3 : filename=bbbb1.doc, content=play the music...

   row 4 : filename=bbbb2.doc, content=coffee and cake
2. second concept -> insert record with groupping, assuming no token twisting

   row 1 : filename=aaaa, content=stack overflow is the site that|-token-|stack exchange is the ....

   row 2 : filename=bbbb, content=play the music|-token-|coffee and cake|-token-|....

Comment: It may be worthwhile having a look at 'Fulltext search engines'. some of them work with mysql.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query` - or any of this family of functions. They are deprecated and will be removed from the next major version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, putting 30,000 records (rows) to the table will be faster. Besides, if you have 30,000 files / records, joining them into fewer rows would violate normal forms, and a violation of normal forms often comes with penalties in terms of speed, consistency and maintainability. You can also expect that a DBMS like MySQL would not interpret `LIKE '%querystring%'` for every single row, but to just-in-time compile it, which means the query will be very very fast.

The simple reason is that if MySQL matches the string, the string will be matched directly. If you perform string matching on PHP on data that's coming from MySQL, it first has to be copied from MySQL to PHP via the SQL interface.

Depending on what you're searching for, you might want to consider computer linguistic algorithms to not just find rows that match but have a qualitative match as well.

**Edit (because of question edit):** You should actually have two or three tables. One table that lists all the documents. One table that maps which page is in which document. And one table that lists the page contents. The page contents and the document mapping can be joined into the same table. Like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Documents (
    id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Pages (
    id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    documentId INT REFERENCES(Documents.id),
    text TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(documentId) REFERENCES Documents(id))
);
```

You would then perform a query like this:

```sql
SELECT Documents.name, Pages.text FROM Documents, Pages WHERE Documents.id = Pages.documentId AND text LIKE '%querystring%';
```

Comment: I have an additional question about the query statement. If I divided the table into two like you said, then how can I query  to get `text='%querytext%'` AND `Documents.category='normal'`? Also, there is a problem that reference is a md5 hash, not a INT number. (for example Documents.uniquehash and Pages.referencehash matches, NOT Documents.id and Pages.documentId)

Comment: You can query it exactly the way you wrote it: `SELECT ... WHERE Pages.text='%querytext' AND Documents.category='normal'`. What do you mean by "reference is a md5 hash"? The reference within the database is whatever you define.